# Groovydocs on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

My enviroment:
OSX 10.7.4
Eclipse SDK

Version: 4.2.0
Build id: I20120608-1400

Does anyone know how to generate groovydocs via eclipse? I cant find any plugins to help me generate them. I have Groovy-Eclipse (Required) & Groovy Eclipse SDK (optional) installed.

If you have any solutions, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run them from the command line.  If you want some amount of Eclipse integration, you can run them as an external tool.  You can create an external tool here:

[image]

In the dialog that pops up, specify the path to groovydoc.  In the argument section, place this (as well as any other options you want):

```
${folder_prompt:running groovydoc?:/Default/file/path}
```

This will open a folder prompt with the default file path specified. The choice of folder will be used as the argument to the groovydoc invocation.

Comment: Thanx! Looks like it might work, but i thnk something is wrong w/ my groovydoc app. im getting the following error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.groovydoc.Main
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:96) at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)

Comment: what version of groovy are you using?  And do you get the same behavior for the command line?  I get the same stack trace when I run groovydoc on groovy 2.0.0 and 2.0.2, but I get the groovydoc help text when I run groovydoc on 1.8.6.  Not sure what the issue is here...

Comment: installed is   groovy 2.0.0_0
  groovy 2.0.2_0 (active).  
i get an error when i try to run groovydoc through cmd line. groovyConsole does work properly